# Can we develop Azure function in both portal and VS at a time?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on HTTP trigger Azure function(C# language).
I have one doubt, Can we develop the code of same azure function in both Azure Portal and Visual studio?
Or only at one place the editing is possible based on the function creation place?
Could someone clarify on this.

Comment: No you can't. Once you have created a function using the portal and you deploy a function created with visual studio the latter will overwrite the portal function. You need to create seperate function apps in your case.

Comment: Hi, any update? If you don't have more doubts, can you [mark the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57f49.png) to end this question?:)

Answer (score 1):

As peter bons said in the comment, develop Azure function in both portal and VS at a time is impossible.

And if you are based on C#, there is no way to develop function on portal. Only C# script can do.

But you can remote debug on VS:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/remote-debug-your-azure-function-app-v2-visual-studio-krish